# Image preview in email Intent not showing when loaded from Assets Folder

Tags: android, android-intent, share, assets, email-attachments

**I have something like the following code:**

```
public void shareImageInEmail(String imageUri){
   Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
   emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Some text");
   emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(imageUri));
   mActivity.startActivity(emailIntent);
}
```

When the `Uri` is grabbed from the media folders (camera albums, etc) everything works fine.
The problem is when I take a `Uri` from the assets folder like this:

```
share("content://com.ex.myapp/logo.png");
```

In that case, the sharing works but when the e-mail client is opened, **the image preview is a grey box**, instead of the actual image. When I send the picture is sent correctly, it's just not showing the preview.

Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: set type like this */* instead of message/rfc822

Comment: their must be star(*) symbol before and after slash. this comment box doesn't support or i don't know how to put that

Comment: Hi Deen. Thanks for your answer, however that did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution will be to copy all contents in Assets to Sdcard and pass 'Sdcard path Uri' as EXTRA_STREAM to Email.

**Sample Code:**

```
public void shareImageInEmail(String imageUri){
       Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);        
       emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");

       emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Some text");

       Log.v(TAG, "imageUri, file://" + imageUri);
       emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + imageUri));
       startActivity(emailIntent);
}
```

Copy all assets to SDCard (Refer: [How to copy files from 'assets' folder to sdcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-in-assets-to-sdcard))

```
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename); //Store in Sdcard
```

And finally call shareImageInEmail as follows,

```
shareImageInEmail(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Image.png");//assets[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I marked it as as solved because I used your approach. Basically it was because other packages cannot directly access my package assets. I'm creating a file using AssetManager.open(uri.getPath().substring(1)) and then adding this file as an EXTRA_STREAM in the intent. This solves the problem for my application.